# Lights out game - the smallest number of moves

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for algorithm that can find solution for [Lights Out game](http://www.neok12.com/games/lights-out/lights-out.htm) with the smallest number of moves. I found solution using Gaussian Elimination however this solution is finding any solution, not necessary the best possible.

The main problem is that there are places on the sides and corners where if you click, only three or four lights will change. Without them it would be possible to solve this problem in O(n²). I thought about trying all possibilities of those places in corners and on the sides but n is too big for this.

Any ideas ?

n - the size of side. n is up to 10.

PS. I'm only looking for solution that can find the smallest number of moves needed to solve given square or say it is impossible.

Comment: A* algorithm should work for such a small grid, I think.

Comment: Arqade has this question as well, with a working answer, here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/strategy-for-solving-lights-out-puzzle - Also make sure to read the comment, which tells you how to figure out the last part.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but no optimality is mentioned there.

Comment: If N is one of the numbers in [OEIS A076436](http://oeis.org/A076436) then there is only one solution, in which case the Arqade answer will provide it but yes, you're right.

Comment: if I get it right it is a FLIP game/puzzle. if you convert this to bit  map + move xor map then you can simply represent solution as `n`x`n` bit number. for small `n` can this be solved by bruteforce quickly and you will receive not only the min number of moves but the click positions as well ...  if you have a big enough integer variable then this is reduced to single `for` + `xor` + `if` statement which is still `O(2^(nxn))` (not counting the move xor map initialization) but usually much faster then any other approach for small `n` ...

Comment: O(2^(n*n)) = 2^100 and it doesn't seem like a good idea. I wrote about idea where you do something similar but only for places in corners and sides + solve the center in O(n^2) but it is still O(2^(n * 4 - 3) * n^2) = 2^37 * 100.

Comment: @IVlad How can I approach this problem with A* ?

Comment: PS. Bruteforce is usable only up to n=6 on current common HW... run times: `n=5 ~500ms` and `n=6 ~11min` if you add multi threading on CPU or GPU then you can significantly lower these times. but the n>=7 is still unreachable ...

Answer (score 2):

It's not too hard to get Gaussian Elimination to return vectors spanning the null space of the move -> lights linear transform. Then you can apply brute force on a space much smaller than 2^100 elements (I wouldn't imagine there to be more than a million possibilities).

Comment: but is that optimal solution? if you got more then one zone solved separately then  I think it could lead to more moves then the optimal solution

Comment: Probably you are right. For n = 9 there is only 2^8 possibilities for some random tests. Can you tell me how can I find all possible solutions ?

Comment: @Badf Basically, you apply the GE-based algorithm for inverting a matrix, with the original matrix side by side with an identity matrix to start. If it breaks, the all-zero row in the original corresponds to a sequence of presses encoded in the adjoined previously identity matrix that has no effect. Try all 2^k subsets of these.